# Lamps appearing on particles

Tags: mesh, objects, particles

I'm using blender 2.8 and i have a scene with a donut with sprinkles for which i used the particles function. But when i try to add any object, every single sprinkle gets equipped with the same object, when i try to delete them, sprinkles disappear too. I'm guessing, it might have something to do with the weight paint i used for the sprinkles. You can check the file here: 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16M--sEhafyabL10aAXjqivKVprbfprCW

Comment: is the lamp being parented to the particle object?

Comment: No, it happens when i add a completely new lamp, without any connections or parenting

Comment: Welcome, Łukasz Siudmak. You can send the file for analysis using this link. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Also, it's better you say what Blender version you're using.

Comment: I'm using blender 2.8

Comment: I managed to upload it to Google Drive, so here's a link:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16M--sEhafyabL10aAXjqivKVprbfprCW?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this image from your particle system:
Your are telling Blender to Render everything that is inside Collection 2 as particles, so every new object that you put inside the Collection 2, will be part of the particles. Just move the lamps to a different collection and you will be good to go.

[image]

Good Luck